# Java Craps applet keeps crashing?

Tags: java, applet

I'm making a craps applet for my programming class and it seems like nothing I'm doing is right? Once I click the button to roll the dice, the dice disappear from the screen and the applet freezes, not allowing me to click anything. If I do win or lose the first roll, then the "Roll dice!" button is disabled (like it's supposed to be), but when I click "Start game!" it doesn't reactivate, though I can click the "Start game!" button. I can't figure out how to keep the point value the same throughout the game. I am so lost and have no idea what the problem is and nothing I do works. Here's my disappointment of code so far:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Craps extends JApplet implements ActionListener {
Button button1 = new Button("Start game!");
Button button2 = new Button("Roll dice!");
Random gen = new Random();
int buttonPressed = 0;
int die1 = 0;
int die2 = 0;
int wins = 0;
int losses = 0;
int point = 0;
String result = "";
Image[] dice = new Image[6];

public void init() {
    setLayout(null);
    setSize(400, 500);
    dice[0] = getImage(getCodeBase(), "dice1.gif");
    dice[1] = getImage(getCodeBase(), "dice2.gif");
    dice[2] = getImage(getCodeBase(), "dice3.gif");
    dice[3] = getImage(getCodeBase(), "dice4.gif");
    dice[4] = getImage(getCodeBase(), "dice5.gif");
    dice[5] = getImage(getCodeBase(), "dice6.gif");

    button1.setBounds(50,300,125,20);
    button1.addActionListener(this);
    add(button1);

    button2.setBounds(250,300,125,20);
    button2.addActionListener(this);
    add(button2);
}

public void paint (Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    //background
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, 400, 500);
    //table
    g.setColor(Color.cyan);
    g.fillRoundRect(50, 50, 300, 200, 50, 50);
    //dice
    g.drawImage(dice[die1], 50+(int)(Math.random()*275), 50+(int)(Math.random()*175), 32, 32, this);
    g.drawImage(dice[die2], 50+(int)(Math.random()*275), 50+(int)(Math.random()*175), 32, 32, this);


    if (buttonPressed == 2) {
        if (die1+die2==0||die1+die2==1||die1+die2==10) {
            result = "Sorry, you lose.";
            g.drawString(result, 50, 385);
            button2.setEnabled(false);
            if (buttonPressed == 1) {
                add(button2);
            }
        } else if (die1+die2==5||die1+die2==9) {
            result = "Congrats! You win!";
            g.drawString(result, 50, 385);
            button2.setEnabled(false);
            if (buttonPressed == 2) {
                add(button2);
            }
        } else {
            while (die1+die2!=0||die1+die2!=1||die1+die2!=5||die1+die2!=9||die1+die2!=10) { //2,3,7,11,12
                int point = die1 + die2;
                int sum = (die1+die2)+2;
                result = "You rolled "+sum+".";
                g.drawString(result, 50, 385);
                g.drawString("The point is "+((die1+die2)+2)+".", 50, 410);
            }    
                if (die1+die2==5) {
                    result = "Sorry, you lose.";
                    g.drawString(result, 50, 385);
            }
        }    
    } else if (buttonPressed == 1) {
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.drawString("Roll 'em!", 50, 350);
    }
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() == button1) {
        buttonPressed = 1;
    }    

    if (e.getSource() == button2) {
        buttonPressed = 2;
        die1 = gen.nextInt(6);
        die2 = gen.nextInt(6);
    }
    repaint();
}


}
```

Comment: What debugging steps have you taken?

Comment: @DaveNewton I've redone the program a couple of times, tried different ways of printing out the results, tried putting different steps in new methods, making the Button into a JButton, different variations of while loops, do-while loops, and if statements, and created a temporary variable to hold the initial roll value in an attempt to maintain a point value.

Comment: ... Did you try debugging it? Printing out values? Writing and testing small parts in isolation? Simply "redoing" it isn't debugging. You need to provide legitimate information; expecting us to play computer and/or run your code without any clues as to what's happening, when, under what circumstances, etc. isn't fair.

Comment: You are doing too much logic in your paint method. Try moving that out into a separate method that runs only when the button is clicked. The painting should concentrate on painting the screen.

Comment: @DaveNewton When I remove the `if (buttonPressed == 1)` section the applet still crashes when I press "Roll dice!" and don't get an instant win/loss. When I remove `if (buttonPressed == 2)`, "Start game!" does its purpose fine.

Comment: I have pretty much everything working right now except for the fact that I can't get the point value to stay constant, it always changes with what the sum value is. My first thought is to use a while loop so that it only gets a value while `rolls = 1`, but the code outside the loop can't "see" it. I don't really know what else to do?

Answer (score 2):

This is an infinite loop:

```
        while (die1+die2!=0||die1+die2!=1||die1+die2!=5||die1+die2!=9||die1+die2!=10) { //2,3,7,11,12
            int point = die1 + die2;
            int sum = (die1+die2)+2;
            result = "You rolled "+sum+".";
            g.drawString(result, 50, 385);
            g.drawString("The point is "+((die1+die2)+2)+".", 50, 410);
        }
```

There are two reasons. The first is that you never update the values of `die1` and `die2` after entering the loop.

The second is because a condition like this:

```
while ( someValue != 0 || someValue != 1 ) {
```

Will always be true. This is because if `someValue` is `0` then it is necessarily NOT `1` and vice versa. Looking at the if/else structure preceding the while loop I suspect you meant for the condition to be `&&` instead of `||`.

Also you should not be doing any program logic in `paint`. Only painting. Not only does this slow down the painting but `paint` is called from outside of your repaint requests. You can't control when the code is run.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't call `add(..)` in your paint method as this will most likely trigger an invalidation, call `paint(..)` again and therefore `add(..)` again.  This loop should continue until some sort of exception or crash happens.  Also, you should reset `buttonPressed` to the initial value of `0` after it is processed in the `paint(..)` method.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you reevaluate your following logic:

```
if (buttonPressed == 2) {
    if (die1+die2==0||die1+die2==1||die1+die2==10) {
        result = "Sorry, you lose.";
        g.drawString(result, 50, 385);
        button2.setEnabled(false);
        if (buttonPressed == 1) {
            add(button2);
        } 
    ...
```

You have `if (buttonPressed == 1)` **inside**  `if (buttonPressed == 2)`, so in this particular place `add(button2);` will never happen.